# Does every operator have a hermitian adjoint?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

If we think of operators as matrices, every matrix can be transposed and its elements can be complex-conjugated. But the identification of the hermitian adjoint with the transpose conjugate comes from inner products. Namely, the hermitian adjoint of $\hat{T}$ is $\hat{T}^{\dagger}$ where $\hat{T}^{\dagger}$ satisfies $$(u,\hat{T}v) = (\hat{T}^{\dagger}u,v).$$ If $T_{ij} = (i,\hat{T}j),$ then $$T_{ij}^{\dagger} = (i,\hat{T}^{\dagger}j) = (j,\hat{T}i)^* = T_{ji}^*.$$ But how do we know that the map $\hat{T}^{\dagger}$ which satisfies the desired relationship exists in the first place? Can we show it without thinking of operators as matrices, just using the inner product? Also, does the relationship $$\big(\hat{T}^{\dagger}\big)^{\dagger} = \hat{T}$$ always hold? Since it seems to be used in the derivation of $T_{ij}^{\dagger}.$

Comment: Perhaps better to ask this question on [math.se]. It does not seem to be much about physics.

Comment: Check the definition on Wikipedia.

Comment: While this is a math question, I think it is of particular interest for PSE users (too)...

Answer (score 6):

The OP is concerned with the finite-dimensional setting, as phrased in the question and comments. So let us consider a complex finite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$. The detailed proofs of the theorems below can be found in books on linear algebra/ functional analysis/quantum mechanics.

**Theorem (Riesz):** *For every linear functional $F:H\rightarrow \mathbb C$, there exists a unique $f\in H$ such that
$$ F(v) = (f,v) \tag{1} \quad ,$$
for all $v\in  H$.*

**Proof:** *Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1,2,\ldots, \dim H}$ denote an orthonormal basis and define the vector $$ f:= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\dim H} F(e_n)^* \, e_n \quad .$$
Expanding any vector $v\in H$ in the said orthonormal basis shows that $(1)$ holds with $f$ defined as above. Uniqueness of $f$ follows from the properties of the inner product.*

Now let $A:H\rightarrow H$ denote a linear operator on $H$.

**Corollary:** *For fixed $u \in H$, the map $ H\ni v\mapsto (u,Av)$ is a linear functional and hence for each $u$, there exists a unique $z_u\in H$ such that
$$(z_u,v)=(u,Av) \tag{2} \quad ,$$
for all $v\in H$.*

This brings us to the following definition.

**Definition (Adjoint):** *The adjoint operator $A^\dagger:H\rightarrow H$ is defined by*
$$  A^\dagger u:=z_u \tag {3} \quad .$$

Definition $(3)$ makes sense precisely because $z_u$ is unique, i.e. we can associate to every $u\in H$ one and only one $z_u\in H$ and we define $A^\dagger$ to be the function which maps $u$ to $z_u$.

**Theorem:** *The adjoint $A^\dagger$ is linear and it holds that* $(A^\dagger)^\dagger=A$.

**Proof:** *Both properties are consequences of the properties of the inner product.*

As a trivial consequence of $(2)$ and $(3)$ it holds that
$$ (u,Av)=(A^\dagger u,v) \tag{4} \quad ,$$

for all $u,v\in H$. This, in turn, implies that $$(e_m,Ae_n)^*=(e_n,A^\dagger e_m)\quad . \tag 5$$

Equation $(5)$ gives the connection to the matrix representations of both operators, i.e. the matrix of the adjoint is the transpose and complex conjugated matrix of $A$ (in some orthonormal basis).

Comment: I read the answer again. The heart of it is in the theorem that says $A^{\dagger}$ is well-defined. Could you at least point me to a proof of that? Stated that way, it's just saying "assume what you want to exist exists" or "there's a theorem that says it does".

Comment: @EM_1 It is well-defined precisely because $z_u$ is unique. Put differently, using the Riesz representation theorem shows that to each $u$ we can associate one and only one $z_u$ such that $(2)$ holds. This allows us to define a function (operator), which we denote by $A^\dagger$, which maps $u$ to the corresponding $z_u$, which is the content of eq. $(3)$. That $A^\dagger$ is linear follows from the properties of the inner product.

Comment: So for a fixed $u$ there's a corresponding, unique $z_u$, and the operator $A^{\dagger}$ is just the map that associates the first to the second uniquely? Is that a reasonable summary?

Comment: Yes, indeed - we *define* the operator $A^\dagger$ to be this map! All the properties you know regarding adjoint operators then follow from this definition.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ be Hilbert spaces and $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{K}$ a continuous linear operator. Let $\mathcal{H}^*$ and $\mathcal{K}^*$ be the topological dual spaces (the bras).

Further let $i_\mathcal{H}, i_\mathcal{K}$ be the Riesz isomorphisms (the maps that sends a ket to a bra i.e. $| \psi \rangle \mapsto \langle \psi |$).
Consider the following diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{H} @. @. \mathcal{H} @>i_\mathcal{H}>>  \mathcal{H}^* \\
@VTVV @. @AT^\dagger AA @AAT^*A \\
\mathcal{K} @. @. \mathcal{K} @>i_\mathcal{K}>> \mathcal{K}^*,
\end{CD}
$$
where $T^*$ is the Banach adjoint of $T$ defined by $T^*( \langle  \psi| ) = \langle \psi| T$. Clearly $T^*$ is linear and always exists (and is also continuous). Therefore we can define $T^\dagger$ to be the unique linear and bounded operator that makes the diagram commute ($T^\dagger = i^{-1}_\mathcal{H}T^* i_\mathcal{K} $).

Now the commutativity of the diagram means that for any $\varphi \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\psi \in \mathcal{K}$:
$$\langle T^\dagger \psi | \varphi \rangle = T^* (\langle \psi |)  |\varphi \rangle = \langle \psi | T \varphi \rangle.  $$

So in total $T^\dagger$ always exist for continuous $T$ and is uniquely defined by the property in the preceding equation.

The definition of $T^\dagger$ for operators that are not continuous is more problematic. It can be found in (almost) any functional analysis book.

Comment: The definition for (unbounded) operators defined on a dense subspace, which basically is the case we are interested in QM, is also straightforward, and e.g. given in the corresponding Wikipedia article.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the content of the answer. Is there a way to address the question in linear algebraic terms?

Comment: @EM_1 Can you be more specific? Which content of the answer are you not familiar with?  What do you mean by "linear algebraic terms"? Do you mean the case of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the usual scalar product? Maybe you could also tell us more about the exact context in which you want to define a hermitian adjoint.

Comment: Starting with a vector space with an inner product and operators acting on that space. Can I use these constructs (almost exclusively) to show that there exists an operator that satisfies the definition of the adjoint given by the 1st equation in the question? I'm unfamiliar with commutative diagrams, banach spaces, and Riesz isomorphisms.

Comment: @EM_1 See e.g. my answer - does that help? Riesz' representation theorem in finite dimensions is more or less trivial.

Comment: @EM_1 You need to use the Riesz isomorphism to show that the Hermitian adjoint exists. The commutative diagram is just a tool to visualize the relevant maps. Saying that it commutes means "that we can follow the arrows in either way". So in the diagram above it means that $ i_\mathcal{H} \circ T^\dagger =T^* \circ  i_\mathcal{K}$. The only Banach space knowledge required here is the notion of continuity (and the fact that $T^*$ is continuous), which is necessary for infinite dimensional spaces. Without it can only be proven for finite dimensions (see the other answer by Tobias Fünke).