# The adjoint of a map

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

Assume that $V=V(m,\mathbb{R})$, $W=W(n,\mathbb{R})$, and $g:V\to V^* $ and $G:W\to W^*$ are two isomorphisms. Given a map $f:V\to W$, define the adjoint of $f$, denoted by $\tilde{f}$, by $G(w,fv)=g(v,\tilde{f}w)$ (by Nakahar's book, page 98), where $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. Why does $\tilde{f}w$ exist so that $G(w,fv)=g(\tilde{f}w,v)$ and what is it exactly?

Comment: It seems a question for [math.se]

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734660/does-every-operator-have-a-hermitian-adjoint) help? It discusses existence, well-definedness and so on for (finite-dimensional, complex) Hilbert spaces... So it may be also helpful for your question.

Comment: Essentially, $G$ and $g$ are dot products, $f$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, and $\tilde f$ is its transpose, an $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: I think there's some confusion with notation. Either $G$ is a function from $W$ to $W^*$, in which case you should write $G(w)(fw)$, or $G$ is a bilinear function from $W\times W$ to $\Bbb R$ in which case you'd write $G(w,fw)$ as you've done.

Comment: Dear @Jakob , thanks for the comment. It helped so much. But I have some problems: here $V$ and $W$ are not Hilber spaces, $f$ is a linear map (necessarily not bounded) from $V$ to $W$ (so not a operator).  So does your answer still hold here? I mean  Riesz Theorem or te definition of adjoint operator.

Comment: Hi. If I recall correctly, there is a version of Riesz' theorem for bilinear forms (under some conditions on the bilinear form and maybe also on the dimensions of the space, I don't know by heart). And actually, you are assuming finite-dimensional spaces, no? I don't have a particular reference here, but you might try to google something. Sorry that I cannot help more right now. Edit: Actually, have a look [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/LinearAlgebra/2008-2009/bilinear-08.pdf), section 4 - does this help?

Comment: See also [this](https://keatonquinn.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/the-adjoint-of-a-linear-map/).

Comment: @Jakob Yes, I meant finite-dimensional spaces. Thank you so much for the note and the link. They are both useful and answer my question. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can also consider to answer your own question, which may also help future readers with similar questions/problems.

Comment: @Jakob Appreciate your favor. You are right. Consider it done. Thanks very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the nice @Jakob comments and links, I answer my question in this way:

We define $\tilde{f}:W\to V$ by $\tilde{f}=g^{-1}\circ f^* \circ G$, where $f^*:W^* \to V^*$ is the pullback of $f$ (i.e. $f^* (g)=g\circ f$). Also we have $$G(w,fv)=G(w)(f(v))=f^*\circ G(w)(v)=g\circ \tilde{f}(w)(v)=g(\tilde{f}(w))(v)=g(\tilde{f}w,v).$$